# How to install Git on the standard openjdk docker image?

Tags: java, git, docker, openjdk-17

Recently started upgrading my app from JDK 8 to 17.

My build infrastructure uses docker containers.  Previously, I was using `openjdk:8u322-jdk`.  So I bumped the docker image to `openjdk:17.0.2-jdk`, but things've changed drastically.

There's no Git installed by default now, I think the underlying OS has changed and the default CMD is "jshell", whatever that is o_O

I don't want to spend time faffing about creating my own docker image with the needed tools installed.
At the end of the day, I just need to run two commands on the build container: `git clone` and `gradlew`.

What do I need to run to get Git installed so I can run a `git clone` and `gradlew`?

Comment: I would build my own image, `FROM openjdk:17.0.2-jdk` and install git with `RUN microdnf install git`. Then use this image for the build system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`microdnf install git` to install git.

Need to execute bash explicitly if you want to connect and run commands.